# Request not completing (nestjs + rxjs with BehaviorSubject)

Tags: rxjs, nestjs

Hi I have some understanding problems with nestjs and rxjs.
I want to create a Service which holds some fetched data to be used in multile controllers. But the call t o the controller endpoint never completes and I'm not sure why exactly...
Some reference to understand my use case. I have some data which changes a few times a month and I have a few controllers which are relying on this data. So my plan was to create a store for the data. Give the controllers access to the store and update the store if needed. As far as I know rxjs BehaviorSubject is exactly suited for such things but I can't figured it out somehow.

Service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class StoreService {

  private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject<Data[]>([]);
  data$ = dataSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {
    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData() {
    const data = this.httpService.get('url to some endpoint');

    data.subscribe(data => {this.dataSource.next(data)});
  }

  getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
    return this.data$;
  }
}

interface Data {

  someField: any;
}
```

Controller:

```js
@Controller()
export class TestController {

  constructor(private readonly dataService: DataService) {
    
  }

  @Get()
  getData(): Observable<Data[]>{
    return this.dataService.getData();
  }
}

interface Data {

  someField: any;
}
```

If i change getData inside the controller from

```js
getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
    return this.data$;
  }
```

to

```js
getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
    return of(this.dataSource.value);
  }
```

I get the response I want and expect, but now every call to the dataService.getData() returns a new observable and thats not what I want.

A few `pipe(tap((value) => {console.log(value)}))` revealed that `dataSource` AND `data$` are "containing" the data I expect, but somehow the controller does not return these values.

As far as I know, it should be possible to use data$ somehow so that the controller only uses the reference to `data$` and any changes to the underlying BehaviorSubject should propagate to the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to use a BehaviourSubject (or any Subject for that matter) in order to solve this. You can use the [shareReplay RxJS operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay).

```
import {Observable, shareReplay} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class StoreService {
  private data$: Observable<Data[]> = this.loadData().pipe(shareReplay(1));

  constructor(private readonly httpService: HttpService) {}

  private loadData() {
    return this.httpService.get('url to some endpoint');
  }

  getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
    return this.data$;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for trying to help me. With your approch im losing the abiliy to call loadData() a second time to update the store. I know that shareReplay() can be used to reduce the amount of calls to the external endpoint but thats not my Problem right now. My Problem is that if the controller returns the observable form behaviorSubject.asObservable() a request to that controller returns nothing (timeout). Im think it has something to do, that the observable from the subject never completes and therefore the controller returns nothing.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. So your observable logic is working just fine but your controller isn't returning anyhting? I'm haven't work with Observables inside of NestJS but it makes sense that the controller will wait for the Observable to complete. You could either use `firstValueFrom(this.dataService.getData())` to convert it into a promise or `this.dataService.getData().pipe(take(1))` to make the observable complete after the first value was emitted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro in nestjs, but the main difference between `of` and `BehaviorSubject` is that `Observable` returned by `of` is completed.

The nestjs documentation says:

> Nest will automatically subscribe to the source underneath and take the last emitted value (**once the stream is completed**).

So looks like you have to add some `takeUntil` operator to your `getData` method.

For example:

```
  @Get()
  getData(): Observable<Data[]>{
    return this.dataService.getData().pipe(take(1));
  }
```